# jQuery -> uncheck a box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a soldier that can wear multiple body armor suits. You can select them easily, but if you click the selected one, it must unequip and uncheck the box. Does anyone have a idea for me how to solve this? A fiddle example would be lovely.

My fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4R3TS/

```
$('#vest1').click(function () {
    $('.block1').show();
    $('.block2').hide();
    $('.vest').addClass('hide');
    $('.vest1').removeClass('hide');
    $('.vest1').css({
        position: 'relative',
        top: '-105px',
        left: '12px',
    });
    $('#right1').fadeIn();
    $('#right2').fadeOut();
});


$('#vest2').click(function () {
    $('.block1, .block2').show();
    $('.vest').addClass('hide');
    $('.vest2').removeClass('hide');
    $('.vest2').css({
        position: 'relative',
        top: '-210px',
        left: '12px',
    });
    $('#right1').fadeOut();
    $('#right2').fadeIn();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Uncheck box with `id="box"`:

```
$('#box').prop('checked', false);
```

Comment: i dont use the input type="checkbox", i use a div for that.

Comment: @DonnyvanV can you specify which elements don't get "unchecked"?

Comment: @DonnyvanV or do you mean that you want that div to *act* like a checkbox and get that check-mark when clicked on?

Comment: Yes Daniel, i created a div that acts like a checkbox. Im making now hidden checkboxes so i can use your example

Comment: You could do this to 'check'/'uncheck' the divs: `$("#vest1").html('&#10004;');` (when checking), and `$("#vest1").html('');` (when unchecking). This code adds/removes a little check mark symbol to the div.

Comment: @DonnyvanV do you mean if I made an example with my code? http://jsfiddle.net/4R3TS/5/

Comment: your example is not working. Do you have a example with HTML checkboxes?

Comment: @DonnyvanV what is not working with my example? "#vest1" and "#vest2" get check marks when they are clicked on, as you wanted if I understood you correctly. I can do an example with checkboxes, but checkboxes are relatively difficult to style, just so you know.

Answer (score 0):

hideI would suggest to position the images in css. I don't get why you should position them each time with jQuery. You could do that once.

I can't find #right1 and #right2 in your code. Is this maybe old code or is this still in use? Its also not in the fiddle.

I don't see anything to be checked when I click the buttons. If you want to add it you can easily do this by adding code to the functions showVest() and hideVest().

```
(function(){
    var selectedVest;

    $('#vest1').click(function () {
        if(selectedVest === 'vest1') {
            selectedVest = '';
            selectedVest();
        } else {
            selectedVest = 'vest1';
            showVest ('vest1');
        }
    });


    $('#vest2').click(function () {
        if(selectedVest === 'vest2') {
            selectedVest = '';
            hideVest ('vest2');
        } else {
            selectedVest = 'vest2';
            showVest ('vest2');
        }
    });

    var showVest = function ( vest ) {
        if (vest === 'vest1') {
            $('.block1').show();
            $('.block2').hide();
        }
        if (vest === 'vest2') $('.block1, .block2').show();

        $('.vest').addClass('hide');
        $('.' + vest).removeClass('hide');

    };

    var hideVest = function ( ) {
        $('.block1, .block2').hide();
        $('.vest').addClass('hide');

    };
});
```

Regards